# Lightning components: what is the easiest way to access the vanilla "this" inside onclick-handlers located in the controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Assume we have markup like this inside a lightning compo

```
<button onclick="{!c.AnyNiceHandler}">Do something</button>
```

Now in the good old pre-Lightning days I was able to use `this` inside `onclick` and `this` pointed to the DOM element of the clicked `<button>`. And this was very helpful!

Probably for security reasons inline JS seems not to work at all

```
 <button onclick="console.log(this);">Do something</button>
```

And even if it would work, it wasn't of much use to me, because I need `this` (the reference to the buttons DOM element) inside of `{!c.AnyNiceHandler}`...

Can we get `this` back somehow from within the controller?

Answer (score 2):

This seems actually to work pretty fine using the event parameter at the controller:

```
AnyNiceHandler: function(component,event,helper){
    console.log( 'this is the old this = ' , event.srcElement); 
},
```